# Using backbone with sequelize/postgres

Tags: backbone.js

I'm working on creating a model in backbone to interact with my postgres database. I'm using backbone.js for the client side and node.js/sequelize.js for the server side. The code given in the backbone tutorial says this:

```
 var UserModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: '/user',
    defaults: {
        name: '',
        email: ''
    }

});
```

Here they are interacting with a users sql database using a RESTful url (I have no idea what that is). Does anyone have any ideas how I can refer to my postgres table? I am beyond confused and have no idea what's going on (this is all really new to me)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A RESTful URL is just a URL for a webservice that uses RESTful principles.  Google can explain that better than I can here, but the basic idea is to integrate the various REST "verbs" (GET, POST, DELETE, etc.) in to the API.  For instance, here's a set of RESTful verbs + urls for an imaginary user API:

```
GET    /user   - returns a list of users
POST   /user   - creates a new user
DELETE /user/5 - deletes the user with ID 5
PUT    /user/5 - updates/edits the user with ID 5
```

Backbone works particularly well if your server-side is designed similarly, but it's not a requirement.

If your server-side API isn't RESTful, you just need to override certain methods on your Models and Collections (most likely `destroy`, `fetch`, `save`, `url`, `parse`, `sync`, and `toJSON`) to do whatever is appropriate for your server.

For instance, you might want to override the `url` method of your model to make it return your server's (unRESTful) URL:

```
url: function() {
    return 'www.example.com/some/very/not/RESTful/' + this.id + '/URL/example';
}
```

Or, if your server returns your objects with an "envelope", for instance:

```
{
    type: 'envelope',
    payload: {
        type: 'user',
        name: 'Bob',
        id: 5,
    }
}
```

you can modify parse to strip it out:

```
parse: function(original) {
    return original.payload;
}
```

As for "how do I refer to my postgres table", if you override the appropriate methods, then call the appropriate Backbone action methods (`fetch`/`save`/`destroy`) on your models and collections, Backbone will make AJAX requests to the URL you define in your `url` override.  Your server can then use any language you want to interpret that request and perform the appropriate operation on your PostgreSQL database.